# Disabling UINavigation Buttons In Array

Tags: button, ios7, uinavigationbar

I've got two buttons on the right side of my UINavigationController that are working as expected. This is the code I'm using to make this happen:

```
// Share Button
UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[shareButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,19,21)];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *shareBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButton)] autorelease];
shareBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Snapback Button
UIButton *navSnapbackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navSnapbackButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,26,21)];
[navSnapbackButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Snapback.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navSnapbackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(snapbackButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *navSnapbackBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:navSnapbackButton] autorelease];
navSnapbackButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Right Toolbar Button Setup
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navSnapbackBarButton, shareBarButton, nil]];
```

I have a simple request: how do I disable a button in this array? For example say under a specific condition I wanted the Share button disabled, how would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a local variable for your UIBarButtonItem *shareBarButton, declare it as a property in your @interface section so that you have access to it in other methods:

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *shareBarButton;

...

Then assign it in your toolbar setup routine as you have done:

// Share Button

shareBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButton:)];

shareBarButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

...

Action for the button looks like this:

-(void)shareButton:(id)sender {

}

...

Then in the shareButton action, or some other method, you can now set the enabled property:

self.shareBarButton.enabled = NO;

if (...) {

self.shareBarButton.enabled = YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ann Taylor is very nice and I will do in that way, but if you don't want to have this UIBarButton like a interface property in your view, you can do this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(performAction:)];
btn1.tag = 0;
UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"_ui_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(performAction:)];
btn2.tag = 1;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[btn1,btn2];
```

And in the disabled method:

```
- (void)performAction:(id)sender
{
  NSArray *_barButtons = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;
  UIBarButtonItem *_barButton;
  for (_barButton in _barButtons) {
    if (_barButton.tag == 0) {
        _barButton.enabled = NO;
    }
  }
}
```

I.